# MS Access Form: Use value of first Combobox to filter options of second Combobox?

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

As an example, let's use food.

Table: **Food**

```
  ID  ||   Type   ||  Name
   1  ||   Fruit  ||  Apple
   2  ||   Fruit  ||  Orange
   3  ||   Veggie ||  Pea
   4  ||   Veggie ||  Corn
```

Combobox 1: **TypeCB**
Row Source (SQL):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Count([Food].ID) AS CountOfID, 
    [Food].Type
FROM [Food]
ORDER BY [Food].Type;
```

(The reason I use "CountofID" is the get the unique Type values, otherwise they're repeated since the ID's are unique)

Now this works perfectly for the first, however, when I try to pull the value over to my next ComboBox, it the second combobox remains empty. Refreshing the Form with the first combobox filled doesn't fix it.

Combobox 2: **NameCB**
Row Source (SQL):

```
SELECT 
    Count([Food].ID) AS CountOfID, 
    [Food].Name
FROM [Food]
HAVING ((([Food].Type)=[Forms]![Food Form]![TypeCB].[SelText]));
```

Is there another/a better way to grab this data?

Comment: Why are you including a Count in these queries? It is not necessary just to return Distinct. If the first combobox value is the Count calc, then this is useless as filter criteria for the second combobox. I have never seen SelText property used like this. I think you should probably remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Count` in the Row Source of your TypeCB because you're only using the Type column. If you leave it in, be sure the `Bound Column` property of TypeCB is set to 2 so the value of the combo box will pick up from the Type column rather than CountOfID.

Your NameCB Row Source is OK, except for the [SelText] property. Change it:

```
  SELECT 
      Count([Food].ID) AS CountOfID, 
      [Food].Name
  FROM [Food]
  HAVING ((([Food].Type)=[Forms]![Food Form]![TypeCB]));
```

If the `Bound Column` property of your TypeCB combo box is set to the column with the Type value, you can reference the control itself to get the value.

In the `After Update` event of the TypeCB combo box, add `NameCB.Requery()` to refresh the NameCB combo box.